# Intellij and vscode doesn't run a Hello World java program

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

[like this the program seem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdH8Q.png)enter image description here

after i setup intellij i tried to run my first java program but it doesn't work and always shows the message of "Abnormal build process termination"
and i tried to work on vscode but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like from your output that you named a folder with a `?` at the beginning `(C:\Users\?...)` and apparently Java doesn't like that. Try moving the project in another folder or try renaming it.

(Post the whole output if you can, it's filled with useful info)

Comment: Post the whole output then, the problem stands after (C:\Users\?...)